# How can I create a DataGridView like HTML table?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

I am developing an application for a restaurant and I have a problem about displaying tables in restaurant.

I want to display tables as a 4x4 HTML Table.

If I execute the query `SELECT Table_Name FROM Tables` and set to gridview, all the data displays in a single row but I want it to display as 4x4 table.

[image: Gridview of the restaurant tables]

Comment: simply place as many GridViews as you want from the tool box is that that you want?

Comment: I suggest you to explain your problem better and share your code, so we can help you efficiently.

Comment: I have no problem about retrieve data to gridview. It is OK. But i want break data and add new row when the count of column greater than 4. For example if we have 6 data in the table in database;                                                                                          data1 data2 data3 data4                                                                    data5 data6

Comment: `DataGridView` is usefulf when you want to show table of data in multiple columns. While you can adapt `DataGridView` to your requirement, but it seems `ListView` control is a better match to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Build a View (SQL Server) or Query (Access) or ??? (????) that returns multiple rows using a UNION

```
SELECT Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4
UNION
SELECT Tab5, Tab6, Tab7, Tab8
etc.
```

Or you could just dynamically build a the same SELECT statement driven by the grid layout you desire.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var collection = new[] { "tbl1", "tbl2", "tbl3", "tbl4", "tbl5", "tbl6", "tbl7", "tbl8", "tbl9", "tbl10", "tbl11" };
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("col3");
            dt.Columns.Add("col4");

            // Create the grid
            var countRows = Math.Ceiling((float)collection.Count() / dt.Columns.Count);
            for (var i = 0; i < countRows; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());

            // Fill the grid
            var countRow = 0;
            var countColumn = 0;
            foreach (var charachter in collection)
            {
                dt.Rows[countRow][countColumn] = charachter;
                countColumn++;

                if (countColumn == 4)
                {
                    countRow++;
                    countColumn = 0;
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```